# inserting to multiple tables - using string values as variable

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, variables

Need to insert values in multiple tables. I have a bunch of CSV files which I am reading. I am loading data to redshift without the s3 configuration so I need to insert data row by row. To make the insert successful this is the script i am using:

```
print(table_names[index])
print(column_value)
print(string_final)
print(row_final)

sql = "INSERT INTO "+table_names[index]+  " ("+column_value+") VALUES("+string_final+")",row_final
print(sql)
cur.execute(*sql)
```

The output which I get is:

```
dim_emp
Source_ID, Source_Name
%s, %s
row[0],row[1]
('INSERT INTO dim_emp (Source_ID, Source_Name) VALUES(%s, %s)', 'row[0],row[1]')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "data_dump.py", line 67, in <module>
    cur.execute(*sql)
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

I guess the issue is single quotes around row[0], row[1]. How can I fix this issue? Please help. PS -Using python3.6, pyscopg2

Comment: replace `,row_final` on line 6 by `% row_final`. Assuming `row_final` is a tuple or a list. BTW your code is open to SQL injections, be careful thought

Comment: No row_final is a string